# How old is "Om Jai Jagdish Hare"? What are the original lyrics?

Tags: hymn

I am teaching myself ***Om Jai Jagdish Hare*** on Bansuri(flute).

What are the official lyrics? Everywhere I see there are slight variations. And some are longer than others.

Also, how old are these Hymns?

Comment: It was written by Shradha Ram Phillauri in 1870s. I'm not sure if he wrote that in Gurmukhi first and then translated or directly wrote in Hindi. So can't say about original lyrics.

Comment: @Aman Wow, Gurmukhi? That is interesting! Isn't that the `script of the Guru` according to Sikhism?

Comment: Yeah, like Hindi's script is Devnagari. Phillauri was a native of Punjab. So, it might have written in Punjabi. I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well [Om Jai Jagdish Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Jai_Jagdish_Hare) is a Hindu devotional song that was originally composed around 1870s by Pandit Shardha Ram.

If you go through the link you will see that it may have been inspired by the [Dashavatara](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/dashAvatArastavaHjayadeva.html?lang=sa) (दशावतार कीर्ति धवलम्) section of Gita Govinda of Jayadeva, a lyrical composition of 12th century, which has the same refrain.

> दशावतारस्तवःजयदेव
>
> (जयदेवकविकृतः) प्रलयपयोधिजले धृतवानसि वेदं, विहितवहित्रचरित्रमखेदम् ।
>   केशव धृतमीनशरीर, जय जगदीश हरे ॥ १॥

You can go through the complete hymn [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/dashAvatArastavaHjayadeva.html?lang=sa).

Comment: It looks like the answer is inspired from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Jai_Jagdish_Hare#History).

Comment: Partially yes, we all need some inspiration @aman :)